# 1D Gaussian Smoothing with Python - Sigma equals filter length?

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing, gaussian

I would like to smooth time series data. For this I would like to use Python.

Now I have already found the function scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d.

For this, the array and a sigma value must be passed.

Now to my question:

Is the sigma value equal to the filter length?
I would like to run a filter of length 365 over the data.
Would it then be the correct procedure to set this sigma value to 365 or am I confusing things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sigma` defines how your Gaussian filter are spread around its mean. You can create gaussian filter with a specific size like below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma1 = 3
sigma2 = 50

def gaussian_filter1d(size,sigma):
    filter_range = np.linspace(-int(size/2),int(size/2),size)
    gaussian_filter = [1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp(-x**2/(2*sigma**2)) for x in filter_range]
    return gaussian_filter

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].plot(gaussian_filter1d(size=365,sigma=sigma1))
ax[0].set_title(f'sigma= {sigma1}')
ax[1].plot(gaussian_filter1d(size=365,sigma=sigma2))
ax[1].set_title(f'sigma= {sigma2}')
plt.show()
```

Here is the effect of `sigma` on the Gaussian filter.

[image]

Later, you might [convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) your signal with your Gaussian filter.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed and easy to understand answer!

But now the question is: Is there a method to determine the sigma? I'm trying to rebuild a methodology and there are unfortunately only information about the filter size.

In my research, I have unfortunately found only imprecise answers.

Comment: It is not possible to determine `sigma` only by the size, as you can see in my examples, e.g., two filters with different `sigma`, but same size. But, you can simply try a few `sigma` values to get the feeling of which one is right for your task, if you have no info. Also, would you consider accepting my answer? This would be helpful for others.

Comment: all right, I've done! Many, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When talking of filter length in a gaussian filter, you must explicit "how much" sigma is your filter length. Filter length and sigma are not the same.

For instance, you may implement a gaussian filter with a window length of 360 and say that this window length correspond to 6-sigma. This is an approximation to 99.7% (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory)

So in conclusion, if you want a window length of 360, you should use the sigma value of 60 in the scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d function. This is the common 6-sigma implementation.